# Who edited my comment? Why?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

On Jason FB's answer [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2711/can-two-civilizations-on-nearby-stars-develop-independently-but-be-at-a-similar#comment5317_2787), I posted a comment saying

> This does not provide an answer to the question.

However, it was recently edited to

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

Who did this, and why?

Comment: I think this is done automatically (notice the OP had less than 50 rep, so he's not yet able to comment on posts that he didn't write). By the way, [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2711/can-two-civilizations-on-nearby-stars-develop-independently-but-be-at-a-similar#comment5317_2787) is a much better link to use in your question -- left click on the time stamp, and select "copy link address," paste it where you need it....took me too long to find your comment ;)

Comment: @Shokhet Thanks for the fact and the link.

Comment: No problem....if you selected that comment out of the menu in the review queue, I'm pretty sure that this is the exact language that is used by SE automatically when you select the "*This does not provide an answer to the question*" option.

Comment: Did you type that comment yourself, or did you pick it out of the menu in a review queue?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I believe I typed it myself, although perhaps I'm mis-remembering. I think I simply typed the first sentence in; I remember seeing the comment posted with only that sentence.

Comment: The comment doesn't show as edited. I am flagging this for moderator attention, mostly for when we get pro tems appointment and diamonds assigned; moderators have access to deleted comments, which might provide a clue. However from superficial looks, it does appear that the comment is as initially posted.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling When a mod edits a comment, it doesn't show (at least not to regular users). [I've had my comments edited before by mods, and seen it happen to others' comments]

Comment: @Shokhet When mods edit a comment, it does indeed cause the pencil icon to show up next to it. (I just tried this on some random comment, and the pencil immediately showed up even in incognito mode.)

Comment: @Doorknob Looking for a comment where I remember this happening....found one of my own, but that one had a pencil anyway because I edited it before the moderator did.

Comment: @Shokhet The pencil icon always shows up, no matter who edits the comment. (I've never heard of nor seen anything suggesting otherwise.) And in any case, a moderator editing a comment is such a rare occurrence that it wouldn't really matter anyway. (In fact, I only recall ever editing comments after converting answers to comments, because comments have a much smaller length limit and sometimes converted answers get cut off.)

Comment: @Doorknob All right then....I've been wrong before, I'll do it again :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find anything relevant in the history there.  There is no deleted comment containing only your first line, for what that's worth.  Moderators can't see revision history on comments, but I understand that developers might have other ways of investigating should they choose to.  (Because this is tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) it will eventually be seen by someone from SE.)

The whole post has since been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize for digging something up that should by all rights be buried, but I now know the answer. I checked through the Low Quality Posts queue and discovered that [I recommended deletion of the answer, along with a bunch of other users](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1830), and I recommended deletion at the exact same time as the comment was posted. So it appears that I had posted the comment in that form originally and completely by accident. No edits were made.

Also, as of this past weekend (10/30/2016), mods can now see the edit history of comments that have been edited. Just for fun, I made an edit to the comment on the deleted post to bring it up, and sure enough, the history showed no other edits besides my test one.

Looks like I simply forgot about the automatic comment message.

Comment: No need to apologize for resolving a bug. :-)